# libreoffice-calc, draw, and impress (ARM64) were automatically removed and are no longer installable

Tags: apt, dependencies, libreoffice, 23.10, arm64

This is a headless Ubuntu 23.10 (ARM64 architecture) server, originally installed several years ago. Yesterday, as part of a routine software (patch) upgrade, the following was done (from `/var/log/apt/history.log`):

```
Start-Date: 2024-03-09  20:36:28
Commandline: apt dist-upgrade
Requested-By: ubuntu (1001)
Upgrade: libreoffice-l10n-en-gb:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-l10n-en-za:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), uno-libs-private:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-uiconfig-impress:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), ure:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), alsa-ucm-conf:arm64 (1.2.9-1ubuntu3.2, 1.2.9-1ubuntu3.3), libreoffice-uiconfig-calc:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libuno-cppu3:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-l10n-tr:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), fonts-opensymbol:arm64 (4:102.12+LibO7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:102.12+LibO7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-style-colibre:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libuno-salhelpergcc3-3:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-help-tr:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-uiconfig-draw:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-help-common:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libuno-sal3:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-style-yaru:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-help-en-gb:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-help-en-us:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-style-elementary:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1)
Remove: libreoffice-calc:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-draw:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-impress:arm64 (4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1)
End-Date: 2024-03-09  20:36:43

Start-Date: 2024-03-09  20:37:53
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: ubuntu (1001)
Remove: libreoffice-uiconfig-impress:arm64 (4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libreoffice-uiconfig-calc:arm64 (4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), lp-solve:arm64 (5.5.2.5-2build3), libcdr-0.1-1:arm64 (0.1.7-1), libpagemaker-0.0-0:arm64 (0.0.4-1build3), libreoffice-uiconfig-draw:arm64 (4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1), libvisio-0.1-1:arm64 (0.1.7-1build7), libfreehand-0.1-1:arm64 (0.1.2-3build2), libmspub-0.1-1:arm64 (0.1.4-3build5)
End-Date: 2024-03-09  20:37:55
```

As you see from above, some important components (like **LO Calc, Draw, Impress**) have been removed by `apt dist-upgrade`. After that, some left components of LO are now in version 4:7.6.5, while others in 4:7.6.4:

```
$ apt --installed list | grep -i libreoffice

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libreoffice-base-core/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 arm64 [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-common/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-core/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 arm64 [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-gnome/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 arm64 [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-gtk3/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 arm64 [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-help-common/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed]
libreoffice-help-en-gb/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed]
libreoffice-help-en-us/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed]
libreoffice-help-tr/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed]
libreoffice-l10n-en-gb/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed]
libreoffice-l10n-en-za/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed]
libreoffice-l10n-tr/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed]
libreoffice-math/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 arm64 [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-style-colibre/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-style-elementary/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-style-yaru/mantic-updates,now 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed,automatic]
libreoffice-uiconfig-common/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-uiconfig-math/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-uiconfig-writer/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 all [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
libreoffice-writer/mantic-security,now 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 arm64 [installed,upgradable to: 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1]
```

**LO Writer** works, but it is in version **7.6.4.1 60(Build:1)**.

However, I am no longer able to re-install the removed packages:

```
$ sudo apt install libreoffice-calc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1) but 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libreoffice-core (= 4:7.6.5-0ubuntu0.23.10.1) but 4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

**Update:**
As a temporary solution, I did:

```
$ sudo apt install libreoffice-uiconfig-calc=4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1   
$ sudo apt install libreoffice-calc=4:7.6.4-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
```

and now **LO Calc version 7.6.4.1** seems to work OK, but in the next `apt dist-upgrade` it will be removed again:

```
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  lp-solve
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libreoffice-calc
The following packages have been kept back:
  libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-core libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-math libreoffice-uiconfig-common libreoffice-uiconfig-math libreoffice-uiconfig-writer libreoffice-writer
  python3-uno
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libreoffice-uiconfig-calc
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 186 kB of archives.
After this operation, 28.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

- Is this related to a problem with the *current* 23.10 ARM64 distribution?
- Is there something that I can do to remedy this problem?

---

Extra information:

```
$ find /etc/apt -iname '*list' 
/etc/apt/sources.list

$ grep -v -e '^#' -e '^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ mantic main restricted
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ mantic-updates main restricted
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ mantic universe
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ mantic-updates universe
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ mantic multiverse
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ mantic-updates multiverse
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ mantic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security multiverse
```

Comment: Looks like this happened due to phased updates but I'm not sure. Any special reason to run `apt dist-upgrade` instead of `apt upgrade`?

Comment: @mook765 No, but I had no problems with `dist-upgrade` in the past several years.

Comment: I use it regularly too, but you need to keep a close look at what apt tells you what it is going to do. It is possible that some packages will be removed using `dist-upgrade` or `full-upgrade`.