Is it possible to install only some parts of LibreOffice snap version?
When I run:
$ snap find  libreoffice
Name         Version   Publisher   Notes  Summary
libreoffice  24.2.2.2  canonical✓  -      LibreOffice is a free and open source office suite
[..]

I see that the whole LibreOffice snap package is available for installation on my system. However, I only need the Writer and Calc applications, but not the rest.
How can I select only the required "sub-packages" for a snap installation of LibreOffice, just the way I could do in apt (.deb) installation?

to accomplish what?  it will not give you a lot of space back ;)  why not remove the snap and install writer and calc from apt?

@Rinzwind I am not able to install the apt version of LO on my aarm64 architecture (23.10) system. The problem I described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507086/ has grown to a state that all LO components were removed from the system and I am no longer able to reinstall the LO apt version on that system.

For the official Canonical-published version of the LibreOffice snap, no, it is only packaged as a full suite.
If you really want to use it as a snap, but without all of its components installed, you might be able to do so on your own (the repository for publishing the official snap would be the logical starting point). Further questions on that approach would then be best directed to the Snapcraft forums.
For what it's worth, the approach taken by Canonical on the snap matches how the LibreOffice team themselves package it for Flathub as well (as the full suite only).
